# How to pass collation options to nodejs mongodb driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Trying to pass the collation options to a bulk write operation like this with the nodejs driver.

```
var bulk = module.client.collection('objects').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i += 1) {
    bulk.find({ _key: key, value: values[i] })
        .collation({ locale: 'en_US', numericOrdering: true })
        .upsert()
        .updateOne({ $set: { score: parseFloat(scores[i]) } });
}
await bulk.execute();
```

But seems like `collation` does not exist on the find object.

`(node:2520) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: bulk.find(...).collation is not a function`

MongoDB docs says it should be there https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.collation/

Is there a way to do it with the nodejs driver?

Comment: which is your mongodb version?

Comment: Using mongodb 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if I use `collection.bulkWrite`

```
var updates = [];
for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i += 1) {
    updates.push({
        updateOne: {
            q: { _key: key, value: values[i] },
            u: { $set: { score: parseFloat(scores[i]) } },
            upsert: true,
            collation: { locale: 'en_US', numericOrdering: true },
        },
    });
}
await module.client.collection('objects').bulkWrite(updates);
```

Found this after digging into the test files at https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/test/functional/collations.test.js#L579